# Use of fgets() and gets()

Tags: c, fgets

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // is for read mode

   if (fp == NULL) {
      printf(stderr, "There was an Error while opening the file.\n");
      return (-1);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
         printf("%c",ch);

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

This code seems to work but I keep getting a warning stating *"warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe."*

So I tried to use fgets() but I get an error which states *"too few arguments to function call expected 3"*.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes: provide the missing arguments, which you can find [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: I dont know which ones I'm missing I'm new to C

Comment: yeah that link you provided helps, thank you.

Comment: `printf(stderr,...` should be `fprintf(stderr, ...`, use [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror), it's better in showing error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) expects 3 arguments: the buffer (same as with `gets`), the size of the buffer and the stream to read from. In your case your buffer-size can be obtained with `sizeof file_name` and the stream you want to read from is `stdin`. All in all, this is how you'll call it:

```
fgets(file_name, sizeof file_name, stdin);
```

The reason `gets` is unsafe is because it doesn't (cannot) know the size of the buffer that it will read into. Therefore it is prone to buffer-overflows because it will just keep on writing to the buffer even though it's full.

`fgets` doesn't have this problem because it makes you provide the size of the buffer.

**ADDIT**: your call to `printf` inside the `if( fp == NULL )` is invalid. `printf` expects as its first argument the format, not the output stream. I think you want to call `fprintf` instead.

Finally, in order to correctly detect `EOF` in your `while`-condition you must declare `ch` as an `int`. `EOF` may not necessarily fit into a `char`, but it will fit in an `int` (and `getc` also returns an `int`). You can still print it with `%c`.

Answer (score 2):

First : Never use `gets()` .. it **can cause buffer overflows**

second: show us how you used `fgets()` .. the correct way should look something like this:

```
fgets(file_name,sizeof(file_name),fp); // if fp has been opened
fgets(file_name,sizeof(file_name),stdin); // if you want to input the file name on the terminal

// argument 1 -> name of the array which will store the value
// argument 2 -> size of the input you want to take ( size of the input array to protect against buffer overflow )
// argument 3 -> input source
```

**FYI:**

`fgets` converts the whole input into a string by putting a `\0` character at the end ..

If there was enough space then `fgets` will also get the `\n` from your input (stdin) .. to get rid of the `\n` and still make the whole input as a string , do this:

```
   fgets(file_name,sizeof(file_name),stdin);

   file_name[strlen(file_name)] = '\0';
```

Comment: `fp` should be `stdin`, `fp` hasn't been opened yet and he wants to get the `file_name` from user input.

Comment: @Kninnug see edit .. please feel free to edit my answer, if you want to change anything else

Answer (score 0):

Rather than ask how to use fgets() you should either use google, or look at the Unix/Linux man page or the VisualStudio documentation for the function. There are hundreds of functions in C, C++ and lots of class objects. You need to first figure out how to answer the basics yourself, so that your real questions stand a chance of being answered.

If you are new to C, you are definitely doing the right thing of experimenting, but take a look at other code, as you go along, to learn some of the tips/tricks of how code is written.